# How to color match object and hdri background

Tags: shaders, hdri

I have an HDRi background with ledges and a photoscanned rock.  The colors/tones of the ledges and rock do not quite match.  I am willing to change the tones of the HDRi rocks OR my single rock - either way as long as they better match.  What is the best way to do this?  I am working in cycles.  The free floating photoscanned rock (right) is redder than the background HDRi ledge (left).  I would like to tone them more similar.  I would think a simple shader setup for the photoscanned rock would do it and I would think this would be basic functionality for 'blending'.  Please advise
[image]

Comment: It's hard to see the real difference because the background image is semi-transparent and that affects the color a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by inserting color correction nodes between the image texture's Color output and the shader's Color input.  In this case, I would probably use an RGB curves node to adjust the red tint, so my shader might look like this:

[image: image texture with RGB curve node]